# Python Script- failing to bypass logon page using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, linux, beautifulsoup

I had a script that would bypass a logon page that looks like this

```
URL="http://mywebsite.com/logon.aspx"
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36"}

username="username"
password="password"
s = Session()
s.verify = False

s.headers.update(headers)
r = s.get(URL)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

VIEWSTATE = soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")['value']
VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']
EVENTVALIDATION = soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']

login_data={"__VIEWSTATE":VIEWSTATE,
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
"__EVENTVALIDATION":EVENTVALIDATION,
"txtUsername":username,
"txtPassword":password,
"btnLogin":"Login"
}

#r = s.post(URL, data=login_data, verify=False)
r = s.post("http://mywebsite.com/logon.aspx", data=login_data)


r = s.get("http://mywebsite.com/SummaryReport/Index")
```

that script was working fine before but then it started running into SSL errors so I changed it so that verify=false for the session

Now I don't get SSL errors but now it won't post the data to logon page, I'm not sure if it is related or not but any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If this is the SSL error you are seeing its a warning and can be ignored.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1004: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'ownwebsite.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
 InsecureRequestWarning,
```

What's failing is the following lines.

```
VIEWSTATE = soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")['value']
```

The content received from the URL doesn't have the expected id __VIEWSTATE and is returning `None`  and trying to access based of key 'value' is causing the error.

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I fix this? And why would it work before but fail to work now?

Comment: Was there any changes done to the website recently? Change of ssl certificates maybe? Are you manually able to access the website from the browser ?

Comment: There are always changes to the website, but I can access the website from the browser. And yes there was recently an SSL change but I thought that shouldn't matter since I had set the session to verify=false

Comment: Are you able to see the id's you are trying to fetch in the script when trying it via the browser?i.e., via inspect element?

Comment: It was dumb little problem. The url just had to be updated from http to https. Frustrating. lol thanks for your help!